# ADD ITEM button in a simple Joomla Module

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla, module

I am creating a simple and FREE joomla module that will slide items added by a user. I dont know how to create a "ADD ITEM" button in the module that will repeat the field in the admin screen of the module to allow the next entry.

Example - Below is how my module backend will look

[image: screenshot]

My Module has a field group

```
<fieldset name="sliders" description="To add an item,Click Add New" label="Item - ADD/EDIT Here">
    <field type="sliders" name="sliders" />
</fieldset>
```

Then I have a fields folder in the module with a sliders.php

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Does Joomla have some docs for this? Have you tried adding a form and a button, or is there a form already on the page? Are there open source modules that you can examine to see how to do this? This is rather broad at the moment.

Comment: Also: do you want to submit with this button, or just do DOM manipulation (to add a new row)? If the latter, what JavaScript library do you have at your disposal? I assume Joomla has something installed by default?

Comment: Well, Joomla already has a backend and form for a module which is controlled by the module's XML. Anyone who has opened a Joomla module will understand what I am talking about. Joomla has documentation to build a custom module and I have built some modules too - Its really easy. The only thing I am stuck with is adding items - defined by the user. If I dont find a solution, I will have to just include 9 set of fields by default -  But again it will be like a train with 9 compartments but needed only the first 3.

Comment: Also, there is no submit process here - It is just saving the module configuration and then  when the page loads, the module on the page uses php to evaluate the config options. For example if the module has a parameter - Load JQuery - Yes/No, I can get the param of the module  - if ($params->get('loadjquery', '0'))

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to add elements to the DOM? That would be broadly just a jQuery problem then, right? Inserting elements, modifying `id` and `name` elements perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

For this you would need to make a new form field which will not be easy.

a simpler (built in) solution would be to use jform repeatable.

https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type

Comment: Thanks Sean - Wohoooo - That was a nice answer. See the code in my answer below that worked.

Answer (score 1):

ok, So Joomla 3 has its own repeatable field option. Just used the code below and worked.

```
<field name="list_templates"
type="Repeatable"
```